# Can I use CSS to change the colour/gradient etc of a telerik html chart?

Tags: html, css, charts, telerik

I currently have a column chart which uses the default appearance. I understand that I can change the appearance of the chart in the html but I was wondering if I can use a css class to define all of this and if so how?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <telerik:RadHtmlChart runat="server" ID="ColumnChart" Transitions="true">
            <ClientEvents OnSeriesClick="OnChartClick" />
            <PlotArea>
                <Series>
                    <telerik:ColumnSeries DataFieldY="Count" Name="Product" />
                </Series>
                <Appearance>
                    <FillStyle BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
                </Appearance>
                <XAxis DataLabelsField="Product" />
                <YAxis>
                    <TitleAppearance Position="Center" RotationAngle="0" />
                </YAxis>
            </PlotArea>
            <Legend>
                <Appearance Visible="false" />
            </Legend>
        </telerik:RadHtmlChart>
    </div>
[...]
```

I send the data to the chart by setting a DataTable equal to the DataSource property of the chart. Thus, if a new product is added to the DataTable I would like it to use the extra data without me having to edit the html too. I need the chart to use standard colours which are set by regulation can I assign these via a stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/appearance-styling

Check out this Link, this might can help you.